# Json strings decode mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am fetching the "form_json" from database which has json saved for all form templates. The code for that is:

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');


$id = intval($_GET['frmid']);
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT form_json FROM form WHERE form_id=$id");    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))     
 {       
$url = $row['form_json'];
echo $url; //Outputs: 2

}
 ?>
```

Now, I want to decode all these jsons which are being saved in row form_json. Is there anyway to traverse or something?

```
   $json ='{"value":"Form Title","name":"title"}';
   var_dump(json_decode($json));
   var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

This is how we decode but this is for one string / one form template. I can have many json strings / many form templates saved in database. I should be able to decode all.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is it just `var_dump(json_decode($url))`?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do for that is, to store the single json strings into an array. Problem is, that your json strings are encoded, so you need to concat them first if you want all results at once:

```
$json = array();
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT form_json FROM form WHERE form_id=$id");    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {       
    array_push($json, $row['form_json']);
}

$json = implode(",",$json); // concats all json strings with commas
```

At this point, you have one large string. To make a successful decode, you have to wrap a container around the string to be a valid parse since your values are already json and you need a container for them:

```
$json = '{"templates": [' . $json . ']}';
```

Now you have a valid json string that can be decoded, either as array or object. For better understanding a simple working example:

```
<?php
    $json1 = '{"value":"Form Title","name":"title"}';
    $json2 = '{"value":"A Message","name":"message"}';

    $arr = array($json1, $json2);
    $json = implode(",", $arr);
    $json = '{"templates": ['.$json.']}';
    $json = json_decode($json, true); // true if you want an array, false if you want an object

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json); // returns a multidimensional array of all templates
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"value":"Form Title","name":"title"}';
$data = json_decode($json);
$value = $data->value; //will output = Form Title
$title = $data->title; //will output = title
```

i hope this help